# How to define condition variable on xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf

I define some style on some button. 
The style supposed to change the button bitmap in 'mouse over'.

The problem is that there are two scenario with two different bitmap => that mean 
     Scenario 1: the original bitmap is B1 and in 'mouse over' it need to be change to B2
     Scenario 2: the original bitmap is C1 and in 'mouse over' it need to be change to C2

Those two scenario need to be on same button. 
In my implementation the original & 'mouse over' bitmaps are hard coded - and i don't now how to change it in the xaml.

I mean that i need some 'if' condition in the xaml that will know if I'm run on Scenario 1 or Scenario 2. . .

How can i do it ?

Thanks for any help.